# Get-UnifiedGroup and Get-Teams: how to make a script in powershell and export it to csv file

Tags: powershell

From this link, in the second answer, i could run the commands.
Plus i would like to add this command below in one script and export all the data to csv file.is that possible?

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline 
Get-unified Group | Select Displayname, whenchanged
```

[How to Office 365 Teams Get-Team and Get-Teamuser results export to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059697/how-to-office-365-teams-get-team-and-get-teamuser-results-export-to-csv-file)

Comment: it's `Get-UnifiedGroup` and not `Get-unified Group`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `Export-Csv` at the end of the pipeline, like this:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | Select Displayname, whenchanged | Export-Csv C:\temp.csv
```

This is the results for example:

```
DisplayName WhenChanged        
----------- -----------        
MyGroup     17/08/2021 08:36:22
All Company 27/07/2021 13:39:57
```

Comment: it won't work unfortunately by adding this to the end after $output | Export-csv -Path C:\BatchWiseUserDetails.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Comment: tested it just now... working as expected just copy the code, of course after you connected to ExchangeOnline using the `Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $YourCredentials`

Comment: @Toto Where does variable `$output` in your comment come from?

Comment: $ouput comes from the answer from the link that I attached in the quesion.

Comment: Yes Get-UnifiedGroup | Select Displayname, whenchanged | Export-Csv C:\temp.csv. This command itself works but when i combined the commands from the second answer in the link with it, it does not work